# selenium webdriver sendkeys intermittent issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web automation framework set up that works pretty well.  I have a constant issue though that when using SendKeys to write to textboxes, quite often a letter gets missed out.  So for example, if my dataset is "TestUserName", something like "TestUerName" gets sent example with a missing letter.

This is a big issue for me, as after the web tests concludes successfully I further check if the database was updated properly.  So in the above example I would go to the UserName column and expect to find TestUserName, but the test would fail because TestUerName is found instead.

Any ideas please?  I am using selenium 2.53.0.

My code below.

```
public void inputValue (Object [][] valuesFromExcel) 
{                        
    for (int rowNow = 0; rowNow < (valuesFromExcel.length); rowNow++) 
    {
        String newValue = valuesFromExcel[rowNow][0].toString();
        if (!newValue.equals("")) 
        {
            WebElement currentElement = driver.findElement(By.id(valuesFromExcel[rowNow][1].toString()));

            if (currentElement.getTagName().equals("input")) 
            {                      
                currentElement.sendKeys(newValue);
            } 
            else if (currentElement.getTagName().equals("select")) 
            {                   
                new Select(currentElement).selectByVisibleText(newValue);                    
            }                               
        }
    }        
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: plz update ur selenium latest is 2.53 i guess

Comment: Please (now, and in general) show us your code before changing the issue by performing updates. It won't be a Selenium bug (though 2.44 is a little old.)

Comment: Hi @rajNishKuMar, I needed your comment as incentive to do so :)  I've updated to 2.53 and had to arrange some things.  But the code above still gives me problems for the sendKeys.  E.G.  The data that should be written is MyNameIsDragonfly but instead MynameIsDragonfly gets written, or in one instance MyName only got written.  This is intermittent though, so a number of times the sendKeys works fine.

Comment: This is my guess please confirm. sendkeys works great for web based application i have not seen any symptom like above.can u plz confirm that when you use sendkeys in the input box is your DOM stable at that point of time or internally it gets refreshed

Comment: Hi also have u tried javascript executor to very the same if not then plz use it like JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('gbqfq').value = 'TestUserName';");

Comment: Hi @rajNishKuMar, re. the first question it is stable.  Re. the second question I just gave it a go and it works fine via javascript.  I still had a problem because the date field is automatically formatted/manipulated whilst the user is entering data so a 'copy/paste' does not work well.  So what I did is that if it is a date I use sendKeys, otherwise i use the javascript.  This works fine, thanks for the suggestion!  I am still confused about why the sendKeys isn't working sometimes though :(

Comment: good that it worked for you .i have a gut feeling that there is something internally happening in the DOM at the time when you use sendKeys thats why it is showing that behaviour

Comment: Hmm I don't know I asked the developers as don't have access to the code myself, and they say no.  But I do suspect that you could be right also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending as a string, send it as char...
Convert the string to char and send each char one by one to the text box. Yes there will be a performance issue, but it works fine. It will not skip any of the letters